# Is it possible that the shape of the noise of a dataset can drastically modify the fit result of a dataset?

Tags: algorithm, curve-fitting, noise, data-fitting

I am trying to check different fit routines over synthetic and real data. Changing the shape of the noise makes the reliability of the fit to be not robust.
Which is the correlation between noise - model estimation?

Comment: This should be asked on [stats.stackexchange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Comment above is true.That said. A typical assumption in fitting via least squares is a normal distribution of errors. If the distribution deviates, especially when non-symmetric, results can change quite drastically. You may look [here](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/robust_regression.html) for Python examples